# Uncaught TypeError on XMLDocument.prototype.onreadystatechange after Chrome 43 update

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have the following piece of JavaScript that when loaded on Chrome with last update (43) throws `Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation` and some parts of my app fail to work.

The code with the problem is this:

```
var doc = null;
if (typeof XMLDocument != "undefined") 
    doc = XMLDocument;

if (doc) {
...
    /* error on this line */ doc.prototype.onreadystatechange = null;
...
}
```

I found that [DOM Attributes are now on the prototype chain](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2015/04/DOM-attributes-now-on-the-prototype) and that there was some similar bug [here](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=684671#c2).

I've also tried the solutions provided in the article with no success. The only solution that came to my mind and seems to work was to catch the exception like:

```
try {
   doc.prototype.onreadystatechange = null;
} catch (e) {}
```

Is there a better way to fix this?

Comment: Why are you using `XMLDocument.prototype.onreadystatechange` rather than `document.onreadystatechange`?

Comment: @AshleyMedway the code will try `typeof Document` if it's not `XMLDocument` but Chrome goes with the `XMLDocument` first so I've removed this from the question in order to be read easily. The code is provided so I'm not really sure why the code is written this way. I've also tried with `doc = Document;` and `doc.prototype.onreadystatechange` and I get the same error.

Comment: You are accessing the definition of the object I.E. the internal code to chrome. You should alter the instance of the object. I.E. `document.onreadystatechange = null;`

Comment: Thanks @AshleyMedway I know that it works with document.onreadystatechange but I was wondering if the line could stay unaltered and somehow do a check before running the code with the problem. Like when you check if an object is null before you call one of it's methods.